# Stop Camera from rotating around a rotating parent

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

I have a rolling marble and would like my camera to follow it. My problem is that my camera is also rotating around my object as it is rotating.

Here's my code.

```
-(void) setupCameraOnMarble:(SCNNode*)marble
{
    [cameraNode removeFromParentNode];

    [marble addChildNode:cameraNode];

    SCNLookAtConstraint *marbleStare = [SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:marble];

    marbleStare.gimbalLockEnabled = YES;

    cameraNode.constraints = @[marbleStare];    
}
```

I'm thinking that a transform constraint should work but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Are you using SceneKits physics-system? iOS 11 adds a [`SCNDistanceConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndistanceconstraint). Do you need a solution for iOS 10 as well?

Comment: @orangenkopf 
Yes I would definitely need a solution for iOS 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to make cameraNode a child of marble?

Because according to SKNode docs: when a node’s coordinate system is scaled or rotated, this transformation is applied both to the node’s own content and to that of its descendants [see SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode)

So i assume you need to un-child camera from marble. And to achive that **followint the object** behavior from camera, you may update camera coordinates somewhere in the code, that moves the marble

Answer (score 0):

I have un-childed my camera to my sphere and made my class a SCNSceneRendererDelegate protocol and added this to the rendering loop:

`-(void) renderer:(id)renderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
[cameraNode setPosition: SCNVector3Make(marbleNode.presentationNode.position.x, marbleNode.presentationNode.position.y + 5, marbleNode.presentationNode.position.z + 10)];
}`

If I log the coordinates of the marble.presentationNode they are changing but my camera still doesn't move!

Comment: The camera and the marble are both children of the same parent? Have you set yourself as the `delegate` of your `SCNSceneView` so that the method actually gets called?

Comment: Yes I have. I also set scnView.isPlaying = YES... I also added a NSLog to return the position of marbleNode.presentationNode. I will answer bellow with the full code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apparently I'm no longer allowed to answer questions! So I can't give you my code @#$!%&

Comment: I suggest you add a transform constraint to the camera instead of adding code to the renderer.